# Tab bar on iOS 11 not appearing

Tags: ios, tabbar, ios11

I am using iOS 11 beta, and the bar buttons not appearing in the tab bar for only the iOS 11, but for older versions, this is working well.

**Note:** I am not using storyboard.

Comment: Provide your code

Comment: I'm using a storyboard and changing the tabbar on viewWillAppear ... the tabbar doesn't show changes until I go to another screen and come back. /maybe/ related?